# Simplification of a mathematical expression: (involving green's function)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, mathematics, greens-functions

We have an expression for the current in $z$-direction:
$$
I_z=\lim_{\eta \to 0}\frac{\hbar}{4\pi}\epsilon_{xyz}\int d\mathcal{E} f\left(\mathcal{E} \right) \mathcal{E}^2 \text{Tr}\left[G_0^Rv_xG_0^Rv_yG_0^R-G_0^Av_xG_0^Av_yG_0^A\right] \tag{1}
$$
here $G_0^{R(A)}=\left(\mathcal{E}-H_0+(-)i\eta\right)^{-1}$ are non-interacting retarded (advanced) green's function; $\epsilon_{xyz}$ is Levi-Civita tensor and $f\left(\mathcal{E}\right)=(e^{\beta\mathcal{E}}+1)^{-1}$ is distribution function.

In the class lecture, Professor said that by using Bloch basis of Hamiltonian $H_0|n\rangle =\mathcal{E}_n|n\rangle $, this expression could be simplified to
$$
I_z=\hbar\sum_n \left[
\Omega_{n,z}f(\mathcal{E}_n)\mathcal{E}_n^2
-m_{n,z}
 \left( 
   2f(\mathcal{E}_n)\mathcal{E}_n+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f(\mathcal{E}_n)}{\partial \mathcal{E}_n}\mathcal{E}_n^2
 \right)
\right]  \tag{2}
$$
with
$$
\Omega_{n,z}=i\epsilon_{xyz}\sum_m \frac{\langle n|v_x|m\rangle\langle m|v_y|n\rangle }{(\mathcal{E}_n-\mathcal{E}_m)^2} \tag{3a}
$$
$$
m_{n,z}=i\epsilon_{xyz}\sum_m \frac{\langle n|v_x|m\rangle\langle m|v_y|n\rangle }{(\mathcal{E}_n-\mathcal{E}_m)}  \tag{3b}
$$

How can I reach to $(2)$ from $(1)$?

**My Attempt:**

Start by opening trace:
$$
\lim_{\eta \to 0}\text{Tr}\left[G_0^Rv_xG_0^Rv_yG_0^R-G_0^Av_xG_0^Av_yG_0^A\right]\\
=\lim_{\eta \to 0}\sum_{nm}\left[\langle n| G_0^Rv_x|m\rangle\langle m | G_0^Rv_yG_0^R|n\rangle-(R\to A)\right]\\
=\lim_{\eta \to 0}\sum_{nm}\langle n| v_x|m\rangle\langle m | v_y|n\rangle 
\left[
\left(\mathcal{E}-\mathcal{E}_n+i\eta\right)^{-2}\left(\mathcal{E}-\mathcal{E}_m+i\eta\right)^{-1}
-\left(\mathcal{E}-\mathcal{E}_n-i\eta\right)^{-2}\left(\mathcal{E}-\mathcal{E}_m-i\eta\right)^{-1}
\right]
$$
I am not sure what to do next. Help please.

Comment: You have to deal with the integration over $\mathcal{E}$, since that doesn’t appear in the result.

Comment: @Ghoster Yes. I just noticed that there is a limit $\eta\to 0$. This way, I should get a delta function. But I am not sure how. I know we have a definition for the delta function as $\pi \delta (\mathcal{E} - \mathcal{E} _n) = \lim_{\eta \to 0}\frac{\eta}{(\mathcal{E} - \mathcal{E} _n)^2+\eta^2}$. But I can't see how this arise in my expression for Trace.